# IIS 6 Virtual directory MVC not working but Subdomain is

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I get the following error when using MVC as a virtual directory

> The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later of the .NET Framework. To compile this Web application for version 3.5 or earlier of the .NET Framework, remove the 'targetFramework' attribute from the  element of the Web.config file.

at url 
blah.domain.com/MVC

but at 
blahmvc.domain.com

I get exactly what i want.

so i figured it was a configuration problem so I deleted the virtual directory 
clicked on 
blahmvc.domain.com and 'Save configuration to a File...'

and then on 
blah.domain.com
new virtual directory from file
Read File
Location
Create A new virtual directory
Alias : MVC
and I get the same error when I try and go to the page

Using IIS6 and .NET 4.0.21006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been slightly different versions of runtimes (betas RC's etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try remove targetFramework parameter in system.web/compilation section of the web.config file. This worked for me.